# How many records we can update,delete by using Data Loader at a time?

Tags: community

How many records we can update,delete by using Data Loader at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  load 5,000,000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation for bulk api limits:

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm

> You can submit up to 5,000 batches per rolling 24 hour period

and

> A batch can contain a maximum of 10,000 records

so it would seem that 50 million in a 24 hour period would be the limit

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the Salesforce Governor Limits:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm

It entirely depends on whether your records have update-/delete-triggers on them, but you can calculate how many records you can process using the information there.

Keep in mind that the Governor Limits count for your batch size, not your amount of batches. You can update/delete as many records as you like using the data loader, as long as your batch size is not too high.